# Pivot algorithm in median of medians

Tags: quicksort

The pseudocode for the `pivot` function for the Median of Medians algorithm is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians.

On the last line, there is a mutual recursion call to the `select` function and you can see that the median of the subarray of medians is passed in as parameter `n` in the `select` function. Unfortunately, they use $n$ in the section above to represent the size of the array as well, but `n` in this function means "n-th smallest."

My question pertains to the
   `return select(list, left, left + floor((right − left) / 5), mid)`.

If we are ultimately trying to find the n-th smallest number, should we be interested in the median of the subarray of medians, or should we be interested in the $n-th$ smallest median in the subarray of medians? If it's the latter, then shouldn't this `mid` be changed to the index for the n-th smallest median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the *pivot* routine is to choose an approximate median. This guarantees that in the next iteration, the array shrinks by a constant amount.

Obtaining an approximate $n$'th smallest element wouldn't necessarily do the trick, at least in the short run. As an extreme example, if you're looking for the second smallest element and the pivot is the smallest element, then the array shrunk by just one element.

This example suggests that the strategy of using an approximate $n$'th smallest element might work; however, it is not completely clear how to find such an element, that is, whether the $n/5$'th smallest element of the median array is an approximate $n$'th smallest element in the original array.

In summary, the median-of-medians algorithm works. You might be able to modify it somehow using a different pivoting strategy while maintaining a linear running time; but the analysis might be more complicated. You can give it a go if you wish.